# ORA-25028: regular trigger body can not start with keyword COMPOUND

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was getting the mutating error for the trigger I created. Hence, I changed my trigger to use compound trigger. I have a compound trigger as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_chpt_update
AFTER UPDATE ON task_status
COMPOUND TRIGGER
/* Declaration Section */
task_id number(15);
ckpt_id number(15);
count_of_ckpt number(15);
record number(15);
ckpt_completed number(15):=0;
total_ckpt number(15):=0;

CURSOR cur_task_ckpt IS
SELECT c.taskid, c.ckpt_id, ts.status FROM checkpoint c INNER JOIN   
task_status ts ON c.ckpt_id=ts.ckpt_id;

AFTER EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
/* Get taskid of the checkpoint status being updated */
SELECT taskid INTO task_id FROM checkpoint WHERE ckpt_id=:new.ckpt_id;
END AFTER EACH ROW;

AFTER EACH STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
/* Get number of checkpoints for the task */
--SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count_of_ckpt FROM checkpoint WHERE taskid=task_id;

/* Checking the assumption */
OPEN cur_task_ckpt;
FOR record IN cur_task_ckpt
LOOP
  IF record.taskid=task_id THEN
     total_ckpt:=total_ckpt+1;
     IF record.status=1 THEN
        ckpt_completed:=ckpt_completed+1;
     END IF;
  END IF;
END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ckpt_completed||' of '||total_ckpt||' checkpoints associated with Task ID '||task_id||'have been completed.');
 CLOSE cur_task_ckpt;
END AFTER STATEMENT;

END trig_chpt_update;
```

But when I execute it, I get an error as `ORA-25028: regular trigger body can not start with keyword COMPOUND` . Please let me know where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to change

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_chpt_update
AFTER UPDATE ON task_status
COMPOUND TRIGGER
```

to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_chpt_update
FOR UPDATE [OF field] ON task_status
COMPOUND TRIGGER
```

**Edit**

After verifying, I confirm that the proper syntax is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER compound_trigger_name
FOR [INSERT|DELETE|UPDATE] [OF column] ON table
COMPOUND TRIGGER
```

Note that Coumpound trigger were introduced in Oracle 11g.

Comment: I did the changes you showed. Now I am getting the following error: `Error at line 17: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "STATEMENT" when expecting one of the following:

   row
The symbol "row was inserted before "STATEMENT" to continue.`

Comment: Trying compound triggers for first time. So, getting a bit confused.

Comment: @ChetanaKestikar Change `AFTER EACH STATEMENT` for `AFTER STATEMENT`.